# How do I get kable and formattable to work together when creating a table in R?

Tags: r, kable, formattable

Both kableExtra and formattable have fantastic features and I'll like to be able to incorporate them both in my tables.

Here is the table formatted using formattable:

```
Health_status = c("Very good", "Good", "Fair", "Bad", "Very bad", "Not stated", "Total")
Number = c(1032169, 453975, 125502, 22095, 5019, 73528, 1712288)
Percent = c(60.3, 26.5, 7.3, 1.3, 0.3, 4.3, 100)
Change = c(37672, 15231, 6536, 1988, 525, 30315, 92267)
Percent_Change = c(3.8, 3.5, 5.5, 9.9, 11.7, 70.2, 5.7)
df <- data.frame(Health_status, Number, Percent, Change, Percent_Change)

df %>% 
  formattable(align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r"),
              list(Health_status = formatter("span", style = style(color = "grey")),
                   Change = color_bar("#71CA97")))
```

Which produces this table:

[image]

I would like to add other features (like a table heading) that I can't seem to do with formattable but can do with kable. However, when I include a the kable package the entire table loses is formattble changes:

```
df %>% 
  formattable(align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r"),
              list(Health_status = formatter("span", style = style(color = "grey")),
                   Change = color_bar("#71CA97"))) %>% 
    kable(caption = "Table1")
```

[image]

Is there a way to include a table heading using just formattable? (I don't think that there is) and if not, is there a way to use both formattable and kable together?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found an example using `kableExtra` and `formattable` that was helpful [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/use_kableExtra_with_formattable.html).

```
library(formattable)
library(kableExtra)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Change = color_bar("#71CA97")(Change),
    Health_status = cell_spec(Health_status, "html", color = "grey")
  ) %>%
  kable("html", escape = F, caption = "Table 1", align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r")) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(4, width = "3cm")
```

[image]