# Heatmap table using Kable in R

Tags: r, kable, formattable

I have created a table in R using Kable. I need to create a heatmap table using `formattable()` and provide a table name.

This is the dataset used:

```
structure(list(Type = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Count = c(38L, 32L, 
13L, 4L), `17-Aug` = c(0.13, -1.09, -1.82, -0.38), `24-Aug` = c(-0.13, 
-0.91, -3.62, -1.51), `31-Aug` = c(-6.84, -6.4, -4.84, -1.29), 
    `07-Sep` = c(-3.31, -0.98, -2.58, 0.8), `14-Sep` = c(-3.24, 
    -0.87, -3.31, 0.56), `21-Sep` = c(1.47, 2.07, -1.73, 0.73
    ), `28-Sep` = c(-9.09, -3.33, -3.93, 0.09), `05-Oct` = c(-1.33, 
    2.96, -0.53, 0.93), `12-Oct` = c(-1.18, 2.8, -0.22, 0.89), 
    `19-Oct` = c(2.76, 4.33, 0.22, 0.87), `26-Oct` = c(-3.49, 
    -0.71, -1.47, 0.09), `02-Nov` = c(8.64, 6.98, 3.07, 1.04)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used the following code to create a heat map table:

```
formattable(df,align = "c", lapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) {
  area(row, col = -2) ~ color_tile("white", "mediumaquamarine")
}))
```

I'm getting a warning message when executing the code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In gradient(as.numeric(x), ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In gradient(as.numeric(x), ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In gradient(as.numeric(x), ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In gradient(as.numeric(x), ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Also, I am unable to provide a table name for this table. I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413937/how-do-i-get-kable-and-formattable-to-work-together-when-creating-a-table-in-r) for a solution but I don't get the solution for this.

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: if the table itself is correct and as you want - the warning should not worry you. For rmarkdown documents you can also prevent printing of the warning.